# Search result problem with Taxonomy Term-Names in the result

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 6, search

I need a solution for following Drupal 6 problem:
In my search results, taxonomy terms are appearing in the summary ->
https://www.dropbox.com/s/reg4yebpuwvgref/Screenshot%202016-06-03%2009.13.47.png?dl=0 ( lp_almhütte_hüttengaudi, lp_bäuerinnen_backen, lp_brandteig, ...) and i can't get them out of there.

In the backend in the content type display settings, there is no option to hide them.

I found out, that the vocabularies are included via the vocabularies itself. So if you edit the vocabulary, there are all content types listed and you have to tick the ones you want to have the vocabulary in.